# How to connect SonarQube to TFS

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, metrics

Somebody knows how to connect SonarQube to TFS in order to get several metrics like CheckIns count per day? or is better generate the TFS metrics in JSON format and read JSON file from Sonar Plugin?

Answer (score 3):

SonarQube is an open source platform providing continuous inspection of your code quality. Usually, SonarQube is used to integrate with **TFS Build**, and send the following data, which is gathered during a build under the governance of quality profiles and gates defined on the SonarQube server.

- results of .Net and JavaScript code analysis
- code clone analysis
- code coverage data from tests
- metrics for .Net and JavaScript

To integrate SonarQube with TFS Build, you need to map Build Definitions to SonarQube projects. Detailed steps you can follow the [SonarQube Installation Guide](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation).

If you want to gain insight into the progress you're making, you can use [TFS Dashboards and reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Report/overview).

If you want to know CheckIns count per day, you can check the history in TFS Web Access:

[image]